# Sending Images whatsapp mobile application and receiving on Server

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapi

I've looked at good amount of API available on the Github and other websites. I didn't found any script API which will be helpful for me to receive the images link sent from Mobile whats app application.

did you found any API or script which will fulfill my requirement or do you have any idea to receive the images links on my server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this unofficial unofficial API in github - [**Chat-API**](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/)

First you need to read their [wiki](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentatio) and understand the workflow , otherwise your number will be blocked. **Use it at your own risk.**

I build a chat-bot using this project. And I would like to share some of experience with you.

1. make sure you are using **PHP version 5.6 or higher**.

---

2. must include the below extensions to support encryption.

   - PHP Protobuf
   - Curve25519 PHP
   - crypto PECL

this link may help you : github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/issues/1180

---

3. Don't message to too many numbers who does't have your number in their contact.

---

4. Use broadcast to send to many numbers.

**To receive image you need to bind a custom function to WhatsProt event manager**

```
$WhatsProtObj->eventManager()->bind('onGetImage', 'onGetImage');



function onGetImage($mynumber, $from, $id, $type, $time, $name, $size, $url, $file, $mimeType, $fileHash, $width, $height, $preview, $caption){
echo "Image url : ".$url;
}
```

Comment: follow this work flow : https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation#whatsapp-workflow . Otherwise you will be blocked.